# Centralized configuration management

Tags: java, configuration, osgi

I'm looking at `Apache Felix`, more particularly the subproject `Configuration Admin Service` that allows managing configuration for multiple components. In the documentation, it's said:

> The Configuration Admin Service is like a central hub, which cares for
>   persisting this configuration and also for distributing the
>   configuration to interested parties. One class of such parties are the
>   components to be configured.

Is there a way to manage configuration of multiple components that run on different `Apache Felix` platform instances?

To illustrate my question, assume there are 5 modularized application servers. Each server consists of multiple bundles installed on a single `OSGi` platform instance. On two platform instances, similar bundles may run with different configurations. I would like to centralize the configuration for all the bundles of all the platform instances, using one instance of the `Configuration Admin Service`.

Do you know where I can find good resources on configuration management with `OSGi` and more particularly with `Apache Felix`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you have a look at Apache Karaf, and in particular at [Karaf Cellar](http://karaf.apache.org/index/subprojects/cellar.html), I think that that does what you want. Apache Karaf runs on top of Felix or Equinox.

Comment: Yes. Cellar allows to create groups of servers and distributes config changes in one machine to the group.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

**Option 1:** You can have a distributed Config Admin service between the frameworks. One of the frameworks will host the 'central' Config Admin, and for the other platforms it will be a remote service. Note that this is transparent for the bundles on the frameworks - they willsee and use the local and the remote service in the same way. However, you will have to implement some hooks yourself in order to achieve this. Check the chapter "13 Remote Services" in the OSGi Compendium spec version 4.2.

**Option 2:** All frameworks have local Config Admin services, and you manage all of them using a remote management system for OSGi. One possibility is Karaf, as mentioned above; another is [mPRM - mPower Remote Manager](http://www.prosyst.com/index.php/de/html/content/98/Other-FOU-%7C-Products-%7C-Remote-Management-Server/). They can both manage multiple Felix frameworks and control configurations centrally.